# Scala Circe JSON Library - Understanding Implicit Encoder in an Example

Tags: json, scala, implicit, circe

I am working with the Scala Circe library. It seems very useful and I want to get better at using it.

One example I have is the following.

Consider the following code:

```
import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.{Json, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.auto._

sealed trait JsonComponent
case class DataSequences(values: Map[String, List[Int]]) extends JsonComponent
case class DataField(data: List[DataSequences], `type`: String) extends JsonComponent

object Example extends App {

  implicit val encodeDataSequences: Encoder[DataSequences] = new Encoder[DataSequences] {
    final def apply(sequence: DataSequences): Json = sequence.values.asJson
  }

  val x = new DataSequences(Map("x" -> List(1, 2, 3), "y" -> List(1, 2, 4)))
  val l = List(DataField(List(x, x), "abc"), DataField(List(x, x), "cde")).asJson

  println(l)
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
[
  {
    "data" : [
      {
        "x" : [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "y" : [
          1,
          2,
          4
        ]
      },
      {
        "x" : [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "y" : [
          1,
          2,
          4
        ]
      }
    ],
    "type" : "abc"
  }
]
```

However, if I comment out the **encodeDataSequences** encoder definition, I get the following instead:

```
[
  {
    "data" : [
      {
        "x" : [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "y" : [
          1,
          2,
          4
        ]
      },
      {
        "x" : [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "y" : [
          1,
          2,
          4
        ]
      }
    ],
    "type" : "abc"
  }
]
```

So now this "values" appears. I do not want the "values" field to show up. I am not sure how the implicit is shaping the Json under the hood, and if someone could highlight what's going on that would be appreciated.

In addition, as a gernal thing, am I writing idiomatic Circe code using that implicit encoder, and if so is there a better way to do what I want?

Comment: Both the JSON seems same, and since you are importing `import io.circe.generic.auto._`
It will automatically create the necessary encoders/decoders using shapeless.